# Django DeleteView not finding DB Object

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My DeleteView Post is returning a `Page not found (404)` error.  It isn't clear to me why.

url.py

```
path('<int:pk>/<int:yr>/<int:id>/deleteit/', views.DeleteIt.as_view(), name='delete-it'),
```

view.py

```
class DeleteIt(DeleteView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_success_url(self):
        client_id = self.object.client_id
        year_id = self.object.year_id
        return reverse_lazy('itemview', kwargs = {'pk': client_id, 'yr': year_id})
```

templates - - POSTing template

```
<form action="{% url 'delete-it' pk=url_pk yr=url_yr id=item_id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
```

[The `pk` and `yr` keys are from a context generator.] So, when I make the `post` request from my template the URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/1/1/3/deleteit/
```

The URL is `/pk/yr/id/`  where `id` is the id of the MyModel object in the database.  The object exists and it has all the right keys.  When I make the POST the object isn't deleted (which I believe is a result of not having a successful url call for the delete.

There is no error trace - but the console says:

```
[23/May/2018 22:53:32] "GET /MyApp/1/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13946
Not Found: /MyApp/1/1/3/deleteit/

[23/May/2018 22:55:10] "POST /MyApp/1/1/3/deleteit/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1797
```

My understanding is that the `get_success_url` isn't called because the error is thrown.  The DeleteView seems very straight forward - so not sure how it is coded wrong.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Your URL is `/MyApp/1/1/3/deleteit/` but you are missing the "MyApp" part in your url pattern. The 404 means it can't map the URL, and it hasn't reached as far as your view class (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DeleteView` trying to find object by `pk` URL argument by default. To search object by `id` URL argument you need to specify [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg):

```
class DeleteIt(DeleteView):
    model = MyModel
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'  

    def get_success_url(self):
        client_id = self.object.client_id
        year_id = self.object.year_id
        return reverse_lazy('itemview', kwargs = {'pk': client_id, 'yr': year_id})
```

Comment: I see - the fact that I've set my `client_id` to `'pk'` is causing that to be the key that the DeleteView is looking at.  So, I need to change override the default with the key for this object by name.  Thanks.